# Getting the merge branch name of a merge commit

Tags: git, github

Git is such a well written piece of software, that you can spend a long time using it without really understanding whats going on.

I'm trying to get the name of the branch which was merged with the master branch most recently, and I don't seem to be getting anywhere with git log, git show etc.

Github has the branch name history when I look at the commits to master, but I'm wondering if this is something that github is keeping track of additionally and not something I can access by git. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Except for the default merge message (`merge branch B` or `merge branch B into T`), Git does not save this information anywhere. Branch names are movable and delete-able, so if the name has been moved or deleted, there's nothing to find.

Comment: Branches are just names. Merges involve only commits, even if (and yes the metaphor can be confusing) we often use branch names to refer to them.

Comment: I see, so the only way I can distinguish classes of merges, is by adding some identifier in the description? Because I can get that str. from git log for instance.

Comment: Why do you need to know the branch name that was originally used?

Comment: I want different deploy scripts to run depending on what kind of branch merge occurred.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, this information is not recorded.

You might consider a [`post-merge` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge), like [this one](https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/using-a-post-merge-git-hook-to-clean-up-old-branches/), which would:

- get the branch that was just merged (through [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))
- use [`git notes add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes#Documentation/git-notes.txt-add) in order to add the the current merge commit the information you want.
  That way, no need to modify the description/merge commit message.

That is a local hook though, that would need to be installed on every cloned repository. If you are alone working on the repository, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

As @torek mentioned in the comment, you can use a message within the merge commit itself.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
commit_subject=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%s)
echo Commit subject: $commit_subject

regex='Merge pull request #[0-9]+ from .+/(.+)$'
[[ $commit_subject =~ $regex ]]
branch_name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo Merged branch: $branch_name
```

Example output:

```
Commit subject: Merge pull request #2574 from RepoName/BranchName
Merged branch: BranchName
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create pull requests (black circle) and merge branch in github, you can find information of a merge commit by clicking in `22 Closed` (red circle)

[image: github]